# Apache server - show page while server is offline

Tags: html, apache, apache2

Since my server is running off my personal laptop, it has quite a lot of down time. Is it possible to have a page that shows up when someone tries to access the site while the server is offline?

Comment: One way I know of doing it, is by using CloudFlare, but that wouldn't have anything to do with it. But you can't do it with only Apache seeing as how the server is offline, and not able to receive requests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, with another server. You can't show pages without server.

Comment: Is there a way to redirect to a page on another server while the primary server is off?

Comment: Yes, but you need to have some kind of load balancer etc for that. In amazon this is possible..

Answer (score 0):

If your server is unreachable, then the user browser shows a default page that explains that your server is unreachable...

With an external service (external server) it is possible. A lot of ways to do it. Look for solutions about `load balancing` for example.

But only with apache on your laptop, I think it is impossible.

Try superuser.com, you'll certainly get more answers about your problem.